# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') when trying to configure dotenv-webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, configuration, dotenv

vue: 3.2.22
webpack: 5.68.0
dotenv-webpack: 6.0.4 (but I also tried 7.1.0 which is currently the latest)

My `vue.config.js` looks like this:

```js
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack")


module.exports = {
  // ...

  configureWebpack: {
    performance: {
      hints: false,
    },
    output: {
      filename: "main.js",
    },
    plugins: [
      new Dotenv(),
    ],
  },

  chainWebpack: config => {
    // ...
  },
}
```

When I run `yarn build` I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')`.

This usage of Dotenv is found in a lot of answers on SO and elsewhere but for some reason it doesn't work for me. What could be the cause?

NOTE: I don't have to use `dotenv-webpack` necessarily. I'm open to alternatives as long as I can use my .env file in Vue.

Comment: Vue uses dotenv out of the box. Use that instead https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have a `.env` file in the folder where the webpack config file is?

Comment: Yes I do, with some variables defined with VUE_APP_ as prefix.

Comment: Then my problem must be something else. When in production, a variable I define in the .env and read with `process.env.myvar` ends up being undefined. I just checked and locally, the value is read correctly. The .env file is identical in both places. What could be the cause or what info would be needed to take an educated guess?

Comment: Make sure to prefix your variable with "VUE_APP_". All variables should start with VUE_APP_ , so your example would be VUE_APP_MYVAR in the .env file, and then can be read as process.env.VUE_APP_MYVAR throughout the app.

Comment: Yep, I already do that. Locally it works but in production the value is undefined.